# Converting Kelvin to Fahrenheit in raster stack using R?

Tags: r, time-series, rasterstack

I have a raster stack with 372 layers with Kelvin temperature. I want to convert Kelvin to  Fahrenheit. I know the function, but do not know how to adjust the code so it can be applied to all layer in a raster stack.

```
fahr_to_kelvin <- function(temp) { kelvin <- ((temp - 32) * (5/9)) + 273.15 kelvin }
```

Comment: check the ```raster``` docs; in particular the ```raster::calc``` function (or maybe ```stackApply```).  You may need to modify your function to accept multiple vectors, do your conversion on each, and return multiple vectors.

Answer (score 0):

Always make a tiny example before trying something on 325 layers of a zillion pixels:

```
> r1 = raster(matrix(seq(32,212,len=12),3,4))
> r2 = raster(matrix(sample(seq(32,212,len=12)),3,4))
> r3 = raster(matrix(sample(seq(32,212,len=12)),3,4))
> s = stack(r1,r2,r3)
> plot(s)
```

Then you can do arithmetic on raster stacks and it works on a pixel-by-pixel basis and doesn't mess up the shape. You can transform to Kelvin by applying your function (once you've fixed the syntax error in your pasted code, left as an exercise):

```
> plot(fahr_to_kelvin(s))
```

You don't need `calc` or `stackApply` or anything. Most functions on rasters work on a pixel-basis.